# Visual studio Build Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I installed the VS 2015 & 2013. And i am trying to Buils my Custom Web Application using the "MSBuild version is 4.0.30319".

I am getting the following error :

```
The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\
   MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\
   Microsoft.WebApplications.targets" was not found.
```

Could any one replay why the folder is not created after VS installation. When V10.0 file will create and which version of VS in need to install ?

But Visual Studio normal build is working. How its working ?

Comment: You checked if you missed any resources to install?

Comment: Do you resolve the issue? if the issue still exist, please feel free let me know

Comment: Still issue is there. If I create a fresh web application in VS2013 or VS2015 by VS default web templates  it Building fine. But custom Web App is not building

Comment: I have update my answer, please check it, in addition, is it a custom web app template? is the custom template create by vs2010? do you use msbuild command to build the project?

Answer (score 0):

Since you install VS 2015 & 2013, please use MSBuild 14.0 (12.0) to build your visual studio 2015 (2013) project.

You may encounter many problems when you use earliest version msbuild to visual studio 2013 and visual studio 2015 project.

Update:

The target files will be found when you install visual studio 2010. Or you could copy the target file to related path manually.

Comment: My clients are not installing any VS versions except VS2013, VS2015. i have installed the visual studio sheel on my machine, so Custom web templates are working in my machine, but failing in client machine.

Comment: please share the project file, such as csproj, in addition, please edit project with notepad, modify related target path to vs2013 (v12.0) or vs2015 (v14.0) and check if it works.

Comment: I changed v10.0 to v12.0 or v10.0 to v14.0. But it still looking for V10.0 folder

Comment: please copy related target file to related folder and check if it works. if the issue still exist, please share the proj file via OneDrive.

Comment: If the issue is resolve, please mark it as answer, it will be beneficial to other comunities

Comment: issue is resolve if i manually copy the files, but your clients are asking why should I need to copy manually. there are not copying the manually. My doubt is how can i resolve this with out copying the V10.0 folder to client machine.

Comment: My doubt is how there are VS developers are by default referring V10.0 folder for build. Is any specific reason for that. see tge bellow tags how default its creating.

Comment: My doubt is how there are VS developers are by default referring V10.0 folder for build. Is any specific reason for that. see tge bellow tags how default its creating.                                                            <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>   <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>                                                           But I created this project in VS 2013, with FW 4.5.2 but still its looking for V10.0 ?

Comment: Please modify the line of <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion> to <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">12.0</VisualStudioVersion> and check if it works.

Comment: Ok i will do my modification. If I modify it will work i know.  But my doubt is why it is looking V10.0 by default.

Comment: Maybe you create the project via vs2010, then upgrade the project to vs2013. but the parameter does not change after you upgraded, which you need to modify it manually. and I create simple project via vs2015, the value is 14.0